# Forcing element be the same height as sibling element?

Tags: html, css

I have the following markup:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">
        info <br/>
        info <br/>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        post <br/>
        post <br/>
        post <br/>
        post <br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
container {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
.sidebar {
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    background-color: #eee;
    width:150px;
}
.post {
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin-left:150px;
}
```

How could I force sidebar adopt the height of post using HTML/CSS?
Both sidebar's and post's height can change in size, but post's height is always bigger than sidebar's.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KK4Yc/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok I'm not quite sure why the other posters are going to lengths that they are, you just need to use the benefit of the `parent->child` relationship that dom elements automatically have:

```
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: #eee;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 150px;
}

.sidebar-wrapper {
  background: #eee;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.post {
  margin-left: 150px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

The above is all the css you should need *(as long as you have a 'fixed colour' or 'repeating background image' side-bar)* and the following is the markup:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">
      info <br/>
      info <br/>
    </div>
    <div class="post" style="background: green;">
      post <br/>
      post <br/>
      post <br/>
      post <br/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Obviously *(and rather annoyingly from a HTML/CSS perspective)* if you don't have 'solid colour' or 'repeating background' regions then you'll have to go with j08691's javascript approach or Diodeus's fixed height container approach *(although Diodeus seems to have changed code now and included part of caligula's answer -- I guess by accident?)*.

Answer (score 2):

Can't do it without JavaScript unless you fake it with faux columns. If you want to use jQuery, it's a one-liner:

```
​$('.sidebar').height($('.post').height());​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/KK4Yc/1/)**

Comment: Would be nice to include a JS version :)

Answer (score 0):

If the container has a fixed height, then yes, otherwise you need to use JavaScript.

```
   body, html { height:100% }

    .container {
        width:100%;
        height:500px;
        border:1px solid #ff0000
    }

#bg {
    background-color: #eee;
    width:150px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute; 
}
.sidebar {
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    background-color: #eee;
    width:150px;
    height: 100%;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to set body and html to `height:100%;` ? I know this is required for when you are snapping elements to the entire height of the page - but for snapping sibling elements to the height of a container you probably meant `.sidebar, .post { height: 100%; }` no?

Comment: No, you really need the body, html in there or this won't work.

Comment: Ok well I guess we'll agree to disagree on that one, but you are still missing setting the height of .sidebar and .post to 100%. Otherwise those elements will just remain their default height and not do what Nick has asked.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do via JS, as [j08691](https://stackoverflow.com/users/616443/j08691) said.
But you can try different approach, with pure css for instance add a grey bg-image to the `.container`, so it will look like the sidebar extends to the bottom, or add additional element with the same purpose ([FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KK4Yc/2/)):

```
.container {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
}
#bg {
    background-color: #eee;
    width:150px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute; 
}
.sidebar {
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    background-color: #eee;
    width:150px;
    height: 100%;
    position:relative;
}


<div class="container">
    <div id="bg"></div>
```